# Feedback and opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback, test-equipment, loop-analysis

Consider:

[image]

Attached schematic is from a broken sampling scope that I have in the lab.
Cathode of D1 is connected to a sampling gate output, which is sealed in a metal cage.

U5 (top right) is the signal amplification chain, and the rest of the signal chain can be found in this link: [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/676447/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-positive-feedback-in-this-opamp-circuit)

From this figure, the part that I am not 100% convinced is the signal interaction between U9.OP1 output and 100 MΩ resistor (highlighted in blue).

I guess the purpose of U9 is to set the gate of Q5.2 to be close to the gate voltage of Q5.1, but from DC perspective there is 100 Mohm resistor placed b/w Q5.2 and U9.OP1.

Meanwhile, the sampled signal from the sampling gate is connected to D1. This needs to be tossed to U5 for filtering and amplification, but I worry about the output impedance of U9.OP1 - if this is working as an ideal opamp, isn't  the output impedance supposed to be very low? if so, then the signal from D1 will experience significant attenuation, right?

I would really appreciate if anyone can explain the feedback mechanism shown in this diagram!

Comment: The schematic could use redrawing for better clarity. But it's not complex. U9 is wired correctly to force the JFET gate voltages to be identical. Even the smallest difference between them is countered. And the JFETs will be reverse-biased, so only tiny leakage currents (picoamps, likely) are involved at their gates. You've got very stiff biasing of the PNPs so that about 15 mA is generated through the 510 ohm resistors, About 5 mA of that is siphoned off by the JFETs, leaving 10 mA for the PNP collectors. The opamp senses any current differences and adjusts to re-balance them.

Comment: I understand the circuit behavior, in isolation. But I didn't know what to write as an answer. I've given a synopsis of what I see. Just no details. I can provide those. But I've no idea if that matters to you. (Can't tell from reading. Could just be me.)

Comment: @periblepsis I also read through circuit concepts from old Tektronix books, and I believe this is some sort of a memory circuit that is driven by a memory gate. From my understanding, the isolation is there so that it only allows signal to pass through when a sampled signal (in a pulse form) hits the cathode of diode. This way, it stores the received pulse over the capacitor, and the rest of signal chain will filter and amplify it. In short, I believe the circuit doesn't do anything in DC (b/c of isolation). the input signal must be mixed with a strobe signal

Comment: @periblepsis but I also would like to hear your opinion!

Comment: I can only describe what I see. Not what I cannot see. And I see nothing attached to D1 or to VG1. Both of those facts make me unable to provide/have the context for understanding the circuit's role. I can discuss what it does. But not why. As before. Because, while I understand *what* a sampling scope does, I have never designed one. I've seen block diagrams that make sense to me. That's it. But knowing something from having *completed one* is quite different from knowing something from a highly simplified block diagram. Reality impinges. So I'm very uncomfortable for that reason.

Comment: I agree with your points. This is a schematic I redrew from a PCB board via reverse engineering. I also had to do some study about how the inside of the sampling scope is designed in the past. I'm here just guessing the possible theory of operation, since I don't have access to the inner side of the sampling gate module either(which is sealed in a metal cage!).

Comment: You can wait for someone who ***is*** familiar with sampling scope design, put it squarely into context they already understand well, and then tell you why this particular functional block is as it is. Or I can offer a description of what I see, but leave understanding VG1 and D1 as your problem. (I have some small ideas from vague context, but the specifics do matter and I don't want to go "hunt-and-peck" with this schematic to make sure what I think needs to surround it is really what surrounds it. So, what's your call here? Go fish for an expert? Or should I cut some bait?

Comment: I would love to hear your description of what you see. sharing a different perspective always inspires me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is. I'm just providing rough numbers. I did ***not*** run this through LTspice or attempt any precision in modeling.

So when I show that the emitters are at \$5.4\:\text{V}\$ then I compute the current through \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$ as \$\frac{13\:\text{V}-5.4\:\text{V}}{510\:\Omega}=14.9\:\text{mA}\$. But I round it as the base-emitter voltage will vary with part and temperature, if not other reasons.

Same thing with the current sink formed by \$Q_3\$. I got rid of that and just approximated it as a simple current sink.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQIN2I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$U_9\$ is arranged so that if the gate of \$Q_{5.2}\$ were to drop slightly, then its drain current would also drop slightly. This would mean *more* current would pass through \$Q_{5.2}\$. That would cause the drop across \$R_6\$ to increase, which would increase the voltage at the (+) terminal of the opamp, which would drive it's output upward, which would pull back up on the gate of \$Q_{5.2}\$, correcting the situation. This is NFB, of course.

JFETs are operated with reverse bias and their leakage currents are in the low picoamps. (I'm concerned about leakage in \$D_1\$, though.) So the \$100\:\text{M}\Omega\$ resistor will barely have any voltage drop across it. Hence, the opamp output will be quite close to both gate voltages. A signal placed at **VG1** will be reflected at the output of the opamp. In every sense, the two JFETs float above the current sink, their gates tracking each other and **VG1**.

\$Q_{5.1}\$ is self-biased, without any input on **VG1**, and the opamp will track that. But I don't know what's tied to **VG1**. Also, \$R_7\$ and \$C_1\$ form a simple RC filter for **VG1**, obviously. So \$Q_{5.1}\$'s gate sees a low-pass filtered result from **VG1**.

The other kink here is \$D_1\$. So long as \$D_1\$ is reverse-biased (not much, though, as again I remained concerned about reverse bias leakage via \$D_1\$ as it affects things via \$R_8\$), the above description holds and the voltage gain vs **VG1** is 1 (excepting that \$C_2\$ can be a bit "peaky" if the value is at low parasitic levels.) Above about \$47\:\text{pF}\$ it's probably fairly flat but then \$C_2\$ may be setting the upper bandwidth limit.

But if \$D_1\$ becomes forward-biased, then \$Q_{5.2}\$'s gate will track that input and ignore the opamp output. Since \$D_1\$ can only conduct in one direction, \$Q_{5.2}\$'s gate can only be pulled down, not up, meaning that less current will be diverted there and more via \$Q_{5.1}\$. There will be a narrow range over which **GATE** can operate to yield extremely high gains nearing as much as 200, or more. But we are talking about a few hundred millivolts around whatever is at **VG1**, at most, because that's how this differential pair will work.

So how **GATE** is driven/used/whatever is really important. If it is pulled enough negative relative to **VG1**, then **VG1** will be ignored. It it is pulled enough positive (so as to reverse bias \$D_1\$ -- and there my concerns over leakage pop up again) then the opamp output tracks **VG1** with a gain of about 1 (depending on the values of the capacitors, of course.) Here, though, if **GATE** is driven by a low impedance source then leakage through \$D_1\$, amplified greatly by \$R_8\$, may be a problem.

If it is in the sweet spot, say a hundred millivolts above or below **VG1** to just pick something, then **GATE** sets the gain applied to **VG1**. (That sweet spot, so to speak, occurs because \$D_1\$ is only diverting a little current and that allows the gate of \$Q_{5.1}\$ to be amplified *a lot* by the opamp. And a problem with that idea is that \$D_1\$ may still have some leakage amplified by \$R_8\$.)

If **GATE** is well below **VG1**, then the opamp will probably just rail at its positive supply and ignore **VG1**. I'm not sure if that's desired. (Probably not.)

The leakage in \$D_1\$ and that value of \$R_8\$ would suggest that **GATE** should closely follow **VG1** (within 10's of millivolts) for the opamp output to accurately track **VG1** and that **GATE** should be set well below the most negative excursion of **VG1** to cause it to be ignored, with the opamp railed/saturated.

That's my limited perspective on it. I've no idea how **VG1** or **GATE** are being used. So guesswork only. Best I can do, ignorant as I am about the details of designing a complete, successful sampling scope.

Comment: thanks a lot for leaving a detailed explanation, as always :D. I 100% agree with all the analysis you did. On top of this analysis, I'm also very convinced that this amplifier works as a lossy integrator with input coming from cathode of diode as a pulse. This pulse will be integrated and toss to U5 at the end. I think they chose integrator to make sure SNR penalty is minimized, and for the sampling scope purpose they only care about final integrated value.

Comment: In fact, I have one extra question regarding this topology: why do they need to use Q5 & Q7? why can't they just use U9 directly? My rough guess is... they may need to get some extra loop gain on top of gain of U9. But I also would like to hear your opinion on this.

Comment: @Emm386 You mean, why not just put the opamp across the drains of the two JFETs and control the gate of one of them with the opamp, rather than go to this extra trouble? I have an idea, having to do with how **VG1** and **GATE** are supplied. But there's no information about any of that, so I can't confirm or refute that thought. If there is an independent reason, one that doesn't require knowing anything about **VG1** or **GATE**, then perhaps this is a good question to ask separately and to be answered by experts and not an untrained hobbyist.

Comment: thanks a lot for your thoughtful comments! as always, I learn a lot from your responses!